# Ticket to Ride multiplayer between OS X and iOS

Tags: ticket-to-ride, online, ios

We've purchased Ticket to Ride for iPhone/iPad iOS and I was wondering if I purchase the desktop version for OS X would we be able to play locally between the two devices.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [game maker's website](http://www.daysofwonder.com/online/en/t2r/), yes:

> Online Play (WiFi or 3G) against other iPad, Android, Mac and PC gamers with Days of Wonder Online support

I would take that to mean that both device need to be online to contact their server to set things up, but cross-platform isn't an issue.

Comment: At the moment, choose the Steam version over the Mac app store one if you can. There are currently (Dec. 9 2015) issues between the different platforms since the last update but our tech team is on the deck and in the end this will be possible to play over WiFi between the different platforms. For now the Mac App Store is a little behind in terms of updates